# Не получается сделать задание по массивам

Tags: c++

> Напишите программу, которая заполняет массив из N элементов случайными
>   целыми числами в диапазоне [ A , B ] и определяет количество
>   положительных трёхзначных чисел в этом массиве, которые не делятся на
>   5.

**Входные данные**

Входная строка содержит три числа: границы диапазона случайных чисел A и B , а также размер массива N . Все числа разделены пробелами. Гарантируется, что 0 < N ≤ 10000 .

**Выходные данные**

В первой строке программа должна вывести N элементов построенного массива, разделив их пробелами, а во второй строке – количество трёхзначных чисел в массиве, которые не делятся на 5.

**Примеры**
Входные данные

```
50 200 10
```

Выходные данные

```
50 54 180 80 91 151 98 74 106 114
3
```

Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, n;
    cin >> a >> b >> n;
    if(n>10000) n = 10000;
    vector<int> v(n);
    srand(time(0));

    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        v[i] = rand()%(b-a+1) + a;
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        if ((v[i]>99) && (v[i]<1000) && (v[i]%5!=0))
            cout << v[i] <<" ";    

    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том,что не знаю как сделать подсчет чисел не кратных 5

Comment: Во-первых, определитесь с языком и удалите лишний тег. Во-вторых, показывайте, что уже СДЕЛАНО, и на каком именно моменте какая именно проблема вылезла.

Answer (score 3):

```
int neKratnyh5 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
  if (v[i] > 99 && v[i] < 1000 && v[i] % 5) {
    neKratnyh5++;
  }
}
cout << "\n" << neKratnyh5;
```

Comment: нейминг шикардосный

Answer (score 0):

Когда что-то решаете, в первую очередь - продумайте механизмы решения, распишите в псевдокоде или блок-схему сделайте там .... Дальше зайдите на cppref и подумайте какие алгоритмы Вам подойдут.

Тут явно выход std::count_if - он подсчитает кол-во элементов удовлетворяющих предикату

Вот пример кода, ввод данных организуете сами.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <functional>


std::vector<int64_t> GenVector(uint64_t size, uint64_t low_bound, uint64_t hight_bound) {
    std::vector<int64_t> vec(size);
    std::mt19937_64 generator(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> uid(low_bound, hight_bound);
    auto gen{ std::bind(uid, generator) };
    std::generate(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), gen);

    return std::move(vec);
}


int main()
{
    const uint64_t size{100'000};
    const uint64_t low_bound{0};
    const uint64_t hight_bound{2'000};

    auto vec{ GenVector(size, low_bound, hight_bound) };
    std::copy(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), std::ostream_iterator<uint64_t>{std::cout, " "});
    std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, "") = '\n';

    std::ostream_iterator<uint64_t>(std::cout, "\n") = std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int64_t i) {return i > 99 && i < 1000; });

    return 0;
}
```